# Python os.startfile() without time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment i am using the following code to open a file from within my Python script, by the way i am starting a program (.exe file):

```
os.startfile(filePath)
time.sleep(20)
```

But is there a way i can do this without using `time.sleep(20)` to wait for the file to open?

Comment: Mind me asking, why do you need a delay on file opening?

Comment: Why are you not using `f = open(filePath, 'r')` to open the file?

Comment: Because it is opening other files and loading libraries and that takes some time

Comment: XY problem what is your real problem?

Comment: my problem is that i need to manualy add a delay to start my program, and if someone with a slower pc is using it, it gives some errors because it didnt have enough time to load all the libraries

Comment: Then your `time.sleep` is the best option known to me as there is no way to tell when the program is "ready" (files loaded and opened, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

Take a look at `subprocess` instead, particularly `subprocess.check_call`, which will wait until the process is terminated.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['start', filePath])
```

Comment: Yes need + gave code example.